# Insertion algorithm can not insert all nodes

Tags: python, list, insert

I am newbie in Python. I want to insert new node into the current route to check whether it makes the route shorter or not. However my code doesn't run well, please show me the mistake. The steps are following:
1. Create random subtour (example: 0-2-0)
2. Get randomly the node which is not visited and check this node in each pair of nodes in current route. If the node satisfy the shorter requirement, we insert it into current node (example: 0-4-2-0).
3. Continue until all nodes inserted into the route.

```
import random
distMatrix = [
        [100, 14, 20, 10, 35, 18, 5],
        [6, 100, 7, 35, 17, 9, 24],
        [8, 35, 100, 36, 27, 3, 15],
        [21, 7, 12, 100, 7, 4, 26],
        [33, 25, 6, 18, 100, 19, 11],
        [6, 2, 22, 30, 9, 100, 8],
        [24, 3, 12, 5,17, 16, 100],
        ]
def get_total_distance(route,d):
    total = 0
    for i in range (len(route)-1):
        pre = route[i]
        succ = route[i+1]
        total += d[pre][succ]
    return total
def insertion(d):
    numNodes = len(d)
    notVisited = list(range(1, numNodes))
    first_random_node = random.choice(notVisited)
    route = [0]
    route.append(first_random_node)
    notVisited.remove(first_random_node)
    route.append(0) #create first subtour
    print("1st",route)
    location = 0
    while len(notVisited) != 0:
        for j in notVisited:
            for i in range (len(route)-1):
                pre = route[i]
                succ = route[i+1]
                check_route = d[pre][j] + d[j][succ]
                current_distance = d[pre][succ]
                if check_route <= current_distance:
                    print(j)
                    route.insert(i + 1, j)
                    notVisited.remove(j)
                    print("2nd", route)
    return route
solution = insertion(distMatrix)
print("The solution for the route is:",solution)
print("The total distance is:", get_total_distance(solution,distMatrix))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
"My code doesn't run well" is not a problem specification.

Comment: @roganjosh That's not correct.  This is a general graph, not a Hausdorff space: the triangle inequality need not hold.  It's quite possible to have AB + BC < AC.

Comment: Of course there are.  In fact, the shipping world has long been full of cases where a two-leg trip is cheaper, in some sense, than a direct route.  FedEx was founded on that principle: instead of shipping directly, ship everything to Memphis, spend a couple of hours moving packages out of their "from" flights and into their "to" flights, and send all the planes back from whence they started.  In fact, your vehicle routing problems should have those cases, trading off a longer route for shorter travel time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157928/discussion-between-prune-and-roganjosh).

Answer (score 0):

As it is, your code doesn't run: there's a syntax error because you named a local function the same as a package you're trying to use: `random`.  Inside your function `random`, you can no longer access the package of that name, because you redefined the name.

Once that is resolved, your code hangs with this output:

```
1st [0, 5, 0]
3
2nd [0, 3, 5, 0]
6
2nd [0, 6, 3, 5, 0]
```

You have a logic problem with this combination:

```
while len(notVisited) != 0:
    print("WHILE", len(notVisited))
    for j in notVisited:
        ....
            if check_route <= current_distance:
                print(j)
                route.insert(i + 1, j)
                notVisited.remove(j)
                print("2nd", route)
```

Your only exit from the `while` loop is to remove everything from `notVisited`.  There's no logical guarantee that will happen -- and when it doesn't, you're stuck in an infinite loop trying to find a shorter route that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks! I understand your point of view here. I should eliminate the while loop here cause it doesn't guarantee I can guarantee the route

Comment: Perhaps not eliminate it, but check instead for the case when there *is* no available shortening.

Comment: In this case, I should use if statement, you mean? However my teacher requires repeat insertion until no more cities remain. What I should do?

Comment: "use an if statement" is not a solution.  Go back to your original algorithm or other basic logic, correct the flaw there, and then post the code you propose for the new logic.